# Pandas DF - заменить значения в в ячейке на значение из словаря

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помощи

Имеется DataFrame в котором есть столбец, где могут встречаться значения как одиночные так и список.

```
37774    186-2, 185-3, 185-2
37850           358-1, 358-4
37927                       
38266                  111-2
38409                  111-2
38508                       
38519                  185-1
41161           185-4, 357-1
42948                  185-1
Name: ARTICLE, dtype: object
```

Имеется словарь

```
aDict = {'185-1': 'some text 1', '186-2': 'some text 2', '185-4': 'some text 3', '186-2': 'some text 5', '309-1': 'some text 4', '366-2': 'some text 11'}
```

Необходимо заменить значение в ячейке на значение из словаря. И оставить без изменения, которых в словаре нетю

Пробовал вариант:

```
df['ARTICLE'] = df['ARTICLE'].map(aDict)
```

Работает только для одиночных значения.

Если в ячейке список - не работает

Comment: А что вы хотите чтобы было в случае, если в ячейке несколько значений - чтобы они все поменялись по словарю?

Comment: я хочу чтобы все значения менялись, одинарные и перечисленные через запятую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разрезаем каждую строку по запятым, получившиеся списки "эксплодим", меняем значения с помощью `.replace()`, далее группируем по индексу и объединяем через запятые.

```
aDict = {'185-1': 'some text 1', '186-2': 'some text 2', '185-3': 'some text 3', '186-5': 'some text 5', '309-1': 'some text 4', '366-2': 'some text 11'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'ARTICLE': ['186-2, 185-3, 185-2', '358-1, 358-4', '', '111-2', '111-2', '', '185-1', '185-4, 357-1', '185-1']})

df.ARTICLE = df.ARTICLE.str.split(', ').explode().replace(aDict).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

print(df)
```

```
                           ARTICLE
0  some text 2, some text 3, 185-2
1                     358-1, 358-4
2                                 
3                            111-2
4                            111-2
5                                 
6                      some text 1
7                     185-4, 357-1
8                      some text 1
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает!!!